# How to automatically size a Window to fit its content

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I'm using C# and Infragistics 15.
I have a WinForm with an UltraGrid and I want to auto-ajust the window's size to the content.
I looked for this and I found SizeToContent property.

But I can not find this property with my window.

[SizeToContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx)

[image]

FrmCVault is my window's name.

This is my windows when I open it at the beginning :

[image]
And this is my window when I scroll down, I'd like to delete the blank at the bottom, to make it fit to the content :

[image]

Comment: This property belongs to WPF Window

Comment: Do you know something similar for what I use ?

Comment: I think it is another question now and completely related to UltraGrid

Comment: Let me know if you ask an new question based or should I remove my answer, because I answered your first question before edit, that completely fit the situation, but now my answer is misleading:)

Comment: That was actually my initial question I did not express myself properly :)

Comment: I Edited the answer and added an option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Set `AutoSize` property of `Form` to true and Set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`.

Design Mode:

[image]

Run Time:

[image]

Also you can Mix this solution with a `FlowLayoutPanel` and set its `AutoSize` to true and `AutoSizeMode` to `GrownadShrink`.

Also you may need to set controls `Padding` and `Margin` if you need more tight design.

## EDIT

Based on your edit, the answer is now a bit different and is related to UltraGrid  control.

If your grid doesn't support auto size, you can use described answer above, while you set the height of grid manually `yourGrid.Height = ((NumebrOfRows+1) * HeightOfRow)` and add additional spaces if you nedd.

Comment: I've edited my post.
I tried what you wrote but it does not work :/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem by changing the value of an option in Feature Picker in Infragistics engine.
I set the default value to the last line.

Comment: @Majestic You are welcome :) Happy to hear that you solved the problem, thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [ScrollBounds](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout~ScrollBounds.html) of the grid to ScrollToFill. You can use code like this:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ScrollBounds = ScrollBounds.ScrollToFill;
```