# How do I fit a form size to fit tight around the size of a panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with a panel, the panel has a textbox and two buttons

This is the size I want the form to be.

[image]

But if I do  `this.Size = pnl.Size;`

Then it comes too small

[image]

Here is a programmatically generated example on form load

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
pnl.Size=new Size(200, 100);
pnl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
Button b1 = new Button();
Button b2 = new Button();
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
b1.Text = "OK";
b1.Location = new Point(3, 58);
b1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
b2.Text = "Cancel";
b2.Location = new Point(103, 58);
b2.Size = new Size(75, 23);
t1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
t1.Size = new Size(200, 50);
t1.Multiline = true;
pnl.Controls.Add(b1);
pnl.Controls.Add(b2);
pnl.Controls.Add(t1);
this.Controls.Add(pnl);

this.Size = pnl.Size;
```

That last line, `this.Size = pnl.Size` isn't making the form big enough. How can I get the form to fit properly like in the first picture? (preferably without having to do lots of arithmetic and without manually figuring it out graphically then inserting the number in)

Comment: Try setting [Form.ClientSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: You can Set `AutoSize` property of `Form` to `true` and Set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`. You may find this post helpful: [How to automatically size a Window to fit its content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32992721/3110834). Probably it's a better option.

Comment: @RezaAghaei maybe though technically I have multiple panels in the form  and I don't want it to shrink around all the contents of the form.

Comment: If you take a look at linked answer you can see a screenshot of the result. Also you can simply test it. Take a look at [Form.AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) property, You can use `AutoSize` to force a form to resize to fit its contents. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Also it seems current accepted answer is also talking about a single panel like you asked in the question *I have a form with a panel*. Did I miss something?

Comment: @RezaAghaei  Well, I didn't say in the question that the form had a single panel, I just said to fit the form aroudn *a panel*.  The reason why I want that, is that I am changing the layout of the form, I have different panels for different layouts. I make one panel visible for one layout, and another panel visible for another layout. The accepted answer is flexible enough that it works for that situation, i.e. fitting the form around a(as asked, not 'the') panel, and not around the entire contents of a form.

Comment: @barlop I just try to help and the one who should be satisfied by the solutions is you. If you are happy now, it's enough for now. You know the requirements better :)

Comment: By the way, invisible items has not any impact on `AutoSize`, so the `AutoSize` approach will work too. Just just keep [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32992721/3110834) solution in mind, maybe someday find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
this.ClientSize = pnl.Size;
```